# Passwordbox Validation.ErrorTemplate not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to show `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the `PasswordBox`. However, it is not showing. On the same form I have a username `TextBox` and the `ErrorTemplate` is displayed correctly.

Xaml for the PasswordBox in a datatempalte:

```
<PasswordBox Grid.Row="3" DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}}">                    
  <PasswordBox.Style>
    <Style>
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
              <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Red" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">*</TextBlock>
              <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
              </Border>
            </DockPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </PasswordBox.Style>

  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <behavior:PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding SPassword="{Binding Path=Password, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

Below is the attached property I am using.

```
public class PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    public SecureString SPassword
    {
        get { return (SecureString)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SPassword", 
            typeof(SecureString), 
            typeof(PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding), 
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;                     
        base.OnAttached();
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, PasswordProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            if (binding.ResolvedSource != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo property = binding.ResolvedSource.GetType()
                    .GetProperty(binding.ParentBinding.Path.Path);

                if (property != null)
                {
                    property.SetValue(binding.ResolvedSource, AssociatedObject.SecurePassword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented `INotifyDataError` interface in the base viewmodel.

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private IDictionary<string, List<string>> errors
        = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            return this.errors.Count > 0;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if ( this.errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) )
        {
            return this.errors[propertyName];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void AddError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        this.errors[propertyName] = new List<string> { error };         
        this.RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    public void RemoveError(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            this.errors.Remove(propertyName);
        }
        this.RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.ErrorsChanged != null)
        {
            this.ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try <ControlTemplate><AdornerDecorator><DockPanel/></AdornerDecorator></ControlTemplate>

Comment: @Nathan, thanks for the suggestion. However that did not address the issue.

Comment: What workarounds have you tried and how are the outcomes? Have you tried setting DataContext in code after InitializeComponent? Have you tried to build a simple bootleg project to show custom validation errors and  modify it step by step to your current code? Have you tried adding a trigger at Validation.HasError to see if default validation error appears?

Comment: @Nathan, I have been trying to debug it using Visual Studio. One thing I noticed was on the TextBox for the Username if there is an error, there is a new property Validation.Errors which contains the validation error. For the password box there is no property for Validation Errors.

Comment: And have you tried setting ValidatesOnDataErrors to true?

Comment: I thought ValidatesOnDataErrors was if you are you using IDataErrorInfo interface. I just tried setting that property to true. I am going to update my question to include code from my base view model which implements INotifyDataError.

Comment: if I bind to the Tag property and raise validation error on that property it seems to work fine. So the problem is with how I have implemented the attached property.

Comment: I'm not specifically knowledgeable about behaviors, but why don't you just set the 'SPassword' attached property instead of hacking into the binding source?

Comment: The problem is definitely, that the error is attributed to the behavior rather than the passworkbox, because the binding is on the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the errors are raised on the `DependencyObject` that hosts the data-bound properties where the validation errors occurs. In your case `<behavior:PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding SPassword="{Binding Path=Password, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" />` means, that you can read your errors inside the behavior.

At that point, I also want to advise against the strange hack that you do to the binding of `SPassword`. Just set the value normally:

```
private void AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SPassword = AssociatedObject.SecurePassword;
    // use debugger to verify, that the validation errors exist. Otherwise, no need for the following line of code
    var behaviorErrors = Validation.GetErrors(this);
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found, how to promote the `Validation.Errors` from the attached behavior to the host control in an elegant way. So basically, your options would be to somehow chain-bind the errors from the behavior to the passwordbox or to create an extra binding to your property, since this binding will use the same validation mechanism and thus set the `Validation.Errors` on the `PasswordBox`. I decided to bind the viewmodel `Password` to `PasswordBox.Tag` for error propagation purposes.

```
<PasswordBox Width="200" Height="100" Tag="{Binding Password,ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,Mode=OneWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behavior:PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding SPassword="{Binding Password}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

Note, that I removed the binding error validation from the binding in behavior, because it's not useful anyway and I added the binding error validation for the `Tag` binding.

One more thing: I changed the `SPassword` property to bind twoway by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SPassword",
    typeof(SecureString),
    typeof(PasswordBoxBehaviorBinding),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Otherwise, make sure to set the binding mode appropriately.